# Is there a Sonar API to get list of projects using a given library/artifact?

Tags: sonarqube

Sonar has a nice feature that allows a user to get a list of projects that use a given library.

I´d like to use this same capability from Sonar´s API but I could not find an obvious way to do that.

Is this kind of search supported through Sonar´s API ?